# Jquery not working on pageload, works after resizing

Tags: javascript

I'm having problems correctly displaying a static div (jumps to top of browser too early). I have found some JQuery code to fix it. I made a custom js and put the code in there. Using console log, i can see the code is being run on page load.

However I only get the desired effect after resizing my window, how do i get this code to work without resizing my browser window?

i added this to my theme info file:

```
scripts[] = js/scroller.js
```

this is my scroller.js file:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function({$(window).off('.affix');console.log( "ready!" );
    $('.navbar-default').removeData('bs.affix').removeClass('affix affix-top affix-bottom')
});})(jQuery);
```

i added this to page.tpl.php

```
<script src="/gamingleagues/themes/gamingleagues/js/scroller.js"></script>
```

Comment: You're adding the .js file twice (In your theme, and again in your tpl). Not sure if that's causing the problem. With your browser, right click and select inspect and check your console for js errors.

Comment: ah thanks, i'll remove one. That isn't the problem though, i get no errors. the js is being executed (i can read the console log on page load). but the result im trying to achieve only becomens visible after resizing browser window